# Type 'string' not supported in restricted C++-AMP

Tags: c++-amp

I'm trying to copy `boost::variant` 2D vector into `array<T,N>`. using the instruction `copy(vectorName.begin(), extentName);` . First I get error because the vector type is `variant` which is understandable. However, after I have changed the vector type to string, I get an error that this type is not supported in restricted amp. The following snippet is the targeted code:

```
    const int x = 100;
    const int y = 100;

    concurrency::extent<2> eA(x,y), eB(x,y), eC(x,y);
    concurrency::array<string, 2> mA(eA), mB(eB), mC(eC);

    tCopyIn.Start();
    copy(masterList[0].begin(), mA);
    copy(masterList[1].begin(), mB);
    copy(masterList[2].begin(), mC);
    tCopyIn.Stop();
```

whereby:

```
vector<vector<vector<boost::variant<string, float>>>> masterList;
```

Is there any way to handle strings in C++-AMP ?

Comment: So, what is the question? Also, what does this have to do with OpenGL, OpenCL and OpenMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is correct C++ AMP does not support string or chars unfortunately. The smallest data type supported is int. There are tricks/techniques to get around this limitation they involve making the chars bigger into ints.

There is a good article about how to do this here: [*C++ AMP: It's got character, but no char!*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/01/17/c-amp-it-s-got-character-but-no-char.aspx) and another here with source code [*String search sample with C++ AMP*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/10/01/string-search-sample-with-c-amp.aspx).

Comment: Thanks svick, it's very helpful